# How to delete recent opened file session on Visual Studio Code?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code

I opened few files during coding (both files in project and out project). After that, I close few in its (by `ctrl+w` and click the 'x' button).
When type `ctrl+tab`, I always see all opened files.

I try to restart VSCode, restart Windows but nothing change.

How do I close unnecessary files?

I use VS Code 1.0 + Windows 10.

Comment: file -> open recent -> clear recently opened

Answer (score 80, accepted):

If you want to clear **a specific item** (not the whole list) from the recently opened list you have to

1. Press `Ctrl + SHIFT + P`
2. Type `Remove From History` (in earlier version it is `Remove From Editor History`) and press Enter
3. Choose/Find the file you want to clear

Source: [link](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/3260#issuecomment-239730713)

**Update 09.04.2020:**

With the release of Visual Studio Code 1.44.0 you can easily remove a file using the UI. You see a closing `x` next to a file in this recently opened files view:

[image: Remove a file from the recently opened files list]

Comment: I was about to ask why I can't see this 'x' button in my VSCode when I suddenly realized that the edit was just 1 day old that my current installation was older than this edit. SO can sometimes be so up-to-minute. :)

Comment: In version 1.47.1 (or some earlier version, I dunno) the menu option changed to ">Clear Search History"

Comment: I'm surprised vsode doesn't just have an `x` button next to each entry under "Recents"

Comment: Filie -> Open Recent -> More ( OR click Cntrl + R) -> Now in the search bar search for that entry -> click on X to delete

Answer (score 74):

I could be mistaken but you don't want to delete, but "clear" recently opened files.  If that is the case, then follow these steps in regards to VS Code version 1.15.0:

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>
- Then, within the Quick Open bar, type in `>Clear Recently Opened`
- Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, restart Visual Studio Code, and you should now see nothing under **Recent**.

Comment: Thanks! I guess there is no way (yet) to clear a specific item in this list and the whole list?

Comment: As I can't edit my comment anymore: Ok, it is possible! I found this: [link](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/3260#issuecomment-239730713)

Comment: If this isn't working for you, make sure you type the `>` and not just `Clear Recently Opened`.  The full text you need to type is `>Clear Recently Opened` including the caret.

Comment: This was really valuable for me when switching between two copies of my repository, I kept accidentally opening files from the other repository copy.

Answer (score 19):

`View > Command Palette... (Cmd + Shift + P)` > `Clear Editor History`

Answer (score 9):

I have just found a workaround which seems to remove a single directory from recents, in case you do not wish to remove all of them.

1. Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> (you may need <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> instead if using a Mac) and select `File: Open Recent...`
2. After you click on that, you should see a dropdown with your recently opened projects. Hover with the mouse on the one you want to delete and towards the end of the line you're hovering you should see a small `x` appearing
3. Click on that `x` and you're all done

Comment: This repeats existing answers.

Comment: Hi @TylerH could you please tell me the author of the answer I'm repeating? By reading the top two answers I'm under the impression that they describe how to remove all your history, not just a single directory. The top answer does mention an update 9.4.2020, however they suggest using "Remove From History" which is not available in the recent version of VSCode. I don't think any other answer suggests using "File: Open Recent...", hence why I believe it is not a repetition. If you disagree please provide more details and I'll double check. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

just click "more" in below the recent list in the welcome page. Then click "x" in the list.
[Refer to this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8gSPf.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

For latest Visual Studio Code (1.54.2):

1. View-Command Palette or Ctrl + Shift + P
2. in the Command Palette dialog box: `File: Clear Recently Opened`
3. Restart Visual Studio Code

Comment: This just repeats existing answers.

Answer (score 0):

To clear recently opened sessions in VS code, please do the following:

1. Press `Ctrl + Shift + P(on Windows)` or `Cmd + shift + P(on MAC)`
2. In the Quick Open bar that shows up, type in `Clear Recently Opened`
3. You can either restart VS code now or choose to continue using it.

Hope this helps. Happy coding!